# Why is my Quick Sort method extremely slow?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

Just trying the iterative version of quick sort and it performs much slower than all sorting algorithms. Where am I going wrong?

```
public static void quickSort(int[] arr) {
    int size = arr.length;
    int count = 0;
    int[] stackArr = new int[size]; 

    stackArr[count] = 0;
    stackArr[++count] = size - 1;

    while (count >= 0) {
        int end = stackArr[count--];
        int start = stackArr[count--];
            
        int pivot = partition(arr, start, end);

        if (pivot - 1 > start) {
            stackArr[++count] = start;
            stackArr[++count] = pivot - 1;
         }
        if (pivot + 1 < end) {
            stackArr[++count] = pivot + 1;
            stackArr[++count] = end;
        }         
    }
}

public static int partition(int[] arr, int start, int end) {
    int countIndex = start ;
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        if (arr[i] <= arr[end]) {
            swap(arr, i, countIndex);
            countIndex++;
        }
    }
    swap(arr, countIndex, end);
    return countIndex;
}

public static void swap(int[] arr, int i, int j) {
    int temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;
}
```

I just tried to write a quickSort() method in java for testing and it performs really slow. I want to find out what is wrong?

Comment: Well, quicksort normally doesn't allocate new arrays. `new int[size]` is suspect.  I also notice the sorting doesn't seem to be recursive, which is suspect too.

Comment: I kinda figured that out eventually, but you'd think the OP would go into a little more how it works if they do something nonstandard like that, and also where they think the bug is at.  Does the bug still occur if the "stack" is replaced by recursion?  Stuff like that.  The current version leaves a lot of questions on the table, imo.

Comment: If you choose the pivot as the first or last element in the array, then your code will take quadratic time when the input is already sorted or reverse-sorted.

Comment: And standard quicksort is quadratic (no matter the pivot) for input arrays that contain a lot of duplicates.

Comment: The question would be improved with an example or examples showing why you think the code is "really slow".

Comment: @markspace if you don't understand the code, perhaps you don't need to comment on the question? It seems like an elementary use of a hand-written stack -- there's something like 10 lines of code that manages the stack in an obvious way. I think if this were professionally-written code, I'd expect a comment saying why it's using a manual stack (and a benchmark), but as a algorithm coding exercise it's not necessary in my opinion.

Comment: @PaulHankin Theese are the running times of my sorting methods for same 100000 size integer array:
Selection Sort: 2082 ms,
Bubble Sort: 996 ms,
Merge Sort: 23 ms,
Quick Sort: 961 ms,
Counting Sort: 20 ms. (Additionally merge sort was recursive but quick sort not because of stackoverflow error.)

Comment: @SertanÖrenay better to include the information into the question, including how you generate the test array.

Comment: (Note the fact that you got a stackoverflow strongly suggests you are running into a quadratic case of quicksort).

Comment: @PaulHankin - for arrays with a lot of duplicates, Lomuto degrades towards worst case, but Hoare improves towards best case. [wiki reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Repeated_elements) .

Answer (score 3):

The code in the question is using the last element as pivot, which is worst case on already sorted or reverse sorted data. Not shown in the question is the code to benchmark the sort functions: it is possible that the first sort sorts the array, and then that sorted array is being used for the rest of the sort functions in the bench mark. To avoid this, use a second array. After creating the randomized array, for each sort test, copy it to a second array and test the sort on the second array.

The question is also using Lomuto partition scheme, which degrades towards worst case if there are duplicate values.

The following code is a near duplicate of Hoare's original version of quick sort which was implemented  on a system without a native stack. To limit stack size to O(log2(n)), the  larger partition indexes are pushed onto the stack, while the smaller partition is handled by looping back to partition code.

```java
    @SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")
    public static void qsort(int[] a)
    {
        if(a.length < 2)
            return;
        // count = (1+floor(log2(a.length)))<<1 
        int count  = (32-Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(a.length))<<1;
        int[] stack = new int[count];
        count = 0;
        stack[count++] = a.length-1;
        stack[count++] = 0;
        while(count != 0){
            int lo = stack[--count];
            int hi = stack[--count];
            while(lo < hi){
                int  md = lo+(hi-lo)/2;     // partition
                int  ll = lo-1;
                int  hh = hi+1;
                int t;
                int p = a[md];
                while(true){
                    while(a[++ll] < p);
                    while(a[--hh] > p);
                    if(ll >= hh)
                        break;
                    t     = a[ll];
                    a[ll] = a[hh];
                    a[hh] = t;
                }
                ll = hh++;
                // push larger partition indexes onto stack
                // loop on smaller partition
                if((ll - lo) >= (hi - hh)){
                    stack[count++] = ll;
                    stack[count++] = lo;
                    lo = hh;
                } else {
                    stack[count++] = hi;
                    stack[count++] = hh;
                    hi = ll;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```